# Remove splash screen manually in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, cordova, splash-screen

On iOS I would like to hold the splash screen up until my app is ready. I see there is a flag in the Cordova.plist called AutoHideSplashScreen -- if I turn this off how to I trigger it's removal on my own?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On iOS you should be able to call `navigator.splashscreen.hide();`

Support for doing this in Android is available since 1.8.0.

Comment: Support for this on Android arrived in 1.8.0.

Answer (score 7):

A quick look in Google and I found [this](http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2011/09/15/ios-phonegap-splash-screen-control/)

Basically what you have to do is:

```
navigator.splashscreen.hide();
```

On Cordova 1.6.0 is:

```
cordova.exec(null, null, "SplashScreen", "hide", [])
```