# Remove splash screen in phonegap for both ios and android

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to remove the splash screen completely in the phonegap application for both ios and android. The `navigator.hide()` function works only after the loading of html page, but i need to remove the splash screen even before that. Please let me know is there any option available for doing this.

Comment: Did the answer below answer your question? If so please mark as answer so it may benefit others in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`Cordova 1.6.0`** – the `navigator.splashscreen` interface has been removed pending cross-platform support. Now You can use :

```
// to hide
cordova.exec(null, null, "SplashScreen", "hide", [])
// to show
cordova.exec(null, null, "SplashScreen", "show", [])
```

I found it Here : [iOS PhoneGap / Cordova – Splash screen control](http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2011/09/15/ios-phonegap-splash-screen-control/)

If you want some other Reference then check [PhoneGap Android SplashScreen Just Got Better](http://adamdempsey.com/tag/phonegap/) in the Link.

You can also go through this [Google Discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/zXPnb2jGnO4).

Hope it will be helpful to you.

Comment: Note to other users: Per the first article in this answer the splash screen is needed to cover the white flash that happens when UIWebView is loaded. Therefore it is recommended not to disable the splash screen at all. This answer did not solve the question as asked, however it did give reason enough that the splash screen should not be removed (possibly even cannot be). Awarded +50 bounty.

Comment: Where would one place this function?

Comment: @SnareChops : He has to write that line in some function and he can call that function after the deviceready event has been fired. #Mentioned in first Link.

Comment: That's a great way to remove it once it shows, but doesn't prevent it from showing in the first place. Though due to my statement above I understand why it should not be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015993/manually-remove-splash-screen-phonegap)

copying the accepted answer for quick reference:

On iOS you should be able to call `navigator.splashscreen.hide();`

Support for doing this in Android is available since 1.8.0.

Comment: This does not remove the splash screen completely. I have the same issue, have completely removed the splash screen files from both locations, cleaned, and re-built my code and the default splash screen is still showing. I want no splash screen at all.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help someone:

Using PhoneGap 2.6.0, what I did is just commenting the:

```
<plugin name="SplashScreen" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
```

line in the PhoneGap's config.xml file (usually located at iOS project root)

Comment: But there is a white screen instead of splash screen.can we avoid that too?