# remove iOS PhoneGap / Cordova – Splash screen control

Tags: ios, cordova

I want to remove the splash screen of iOS Phonegap. I have tried many things:

- I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135751/remove-splash-screen-in-phonegap-for-both-ios-and-android)
- I have also checked [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/zXPnb2jGnO4).
- I have tried:

  `cordova.exec(null, null, "SplashScreen", "hide", []);`
  `navigator.splashscreen.hide();`

I have also removed from `config.xml`. I have also removed res/screen images.
But nothing worked. Is there any other way to remove it? Please help me.

Comment: ie u dont need any splash screen for ur app is it? @Bikash

Comment: yes. I just remove splash screens for all. android,ios....

Comment: Android is working f9 but ios shows splash screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your \platforms\android\assets\www. There may be a config.xml file. You can also configure the. Let me know what happened.

Comment: I didn't got what you said. I can also configure what?